# Why is the density of atoms in space so much higher than the baryon density from BBN and CMB?

Tags: cosmology, big-bang, baryons, nucleosynthesis

If you ask the question: "how many atoms per cubic meter in space", you can get a consensus of around $5$ atoms per cubic cm or about $5\times 10^6\space \text{atoms}\space m^{-3}$. If we assume these are hydrogen atoms, that works out to a density of $$5\times 10^6\space \text{atoms}\space m^{-3}\times 1.67\times 10^{-27}\space kg=8.37\times 10^{-21} \space kg\space m^{-3}$$
However, if you ask about the "baryon density", then using BBN and CMB, you'll get an answer of:
$$0.022\cdot \rho_{CRIT}=4.2\times 10^{-28} \space kg\space m^{-3}$$
Is this a problem?  Obviously the baryon density from BBN is for the entirety of space and the other is a local measurement for IGM, but how do you bridge $7$ orders of magnitude of density difference between the IGM and the rest of space?  Do we really suspect the voids are $0.00000001$ times less dense than the IGM?

Comment: Which type of hydrogen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_medium#Interstellar_matter In Moleculer clouds it seems the hydrogen density is $10^2 - 10^6cm^{-3}$ but in other places its about $10$ $0.2$ or less.

Comment: Another way to calculate the baryon density can be using the photon baryon ratio

Comment: @Layla - The baryon photon ratio is a guess.  It's the big free variable in BBN.  It's the same value as $0.022\times \rho_{CRIT}$.  That's basically the motivation for this question: is the estimate of the baryon ratio from BBN compatible with what we know about atoms per $cm^3$ in our part of the galactic neighborhood?  It seems like $10^{-7}$ is a pretty huge density gradient between the local estimates and the baryon value from BBN.

Comment: @Layla - I'm sorry, I can't make out your first answer.  I'd need clear units to understand what you're suggesting.  Could you try again, please.

Comment: Your calculations are correct but the value of the density is problematic. Are you comparing Interstellar medium, intergalactic medium etc. For instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warm–hot_intergalactic_medium

Comment: or https://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/I/Intergalactic+Medium#:~:text=With%20temperatures%20of%20millions%20of,rarefied%20environments%20in%20the%20Universe.

Comment: The BBN and CMB value for baryonic density come from a free parameter - it's a guess - a guess that's common to the model, but still a guess.  That makes it a hypothesis, not a fact.  I want to know what observations there are to prove or disprove this hypothesis (that are not model dependent).  If IGN is $10^{-27}\space kg\space m^{-3}$, then the BBN model predictions are off by a factor of 10 from the observations.

Comment: I read the link you sent.  Thanks, but apparently those numbers, again, come back to $\Lambda CDM$ model assumptions.  You can't point to a computer simulation based on your model and say that's evidence for your model.